# How to convert Json file to Dictionary using C#-Unity

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to take a Json data set in Unity-C# and turn it into a Dictionary

```
{
1:
    {
        "uni_number": 001,
        "level" : 3,
        "Hp" : 15
    },
    2:
    {
        "uni_number": 000,
        "level" : 0,
        "Hp" : 0
    }
}
```

(I can have the intigers strings if needed) I also need to turn the dictionary file back into a json file when I want to save the game.

I've checked a couple of different StackOverflow questions and I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried using JsonUtility to parse it into a Dictionary.

Here's the json file I want to turn into a dictionary

```
string json = @"1:{""uni_number"": 001,""level"" : 3,""Hp"" : 15},2:{""uni_number"": 000,""level"" : 0,""Hp"" : 0}";
```

This is one of the things that I tried if I can get it to work than I should be able to finish it from there after I add another depth to it.

```
string json = @"{""uni_number"": ""001"",""level"" : ""3"", ""Hp"": ""15""}";

Dictionary<string, string> loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

This doesn't give me an error, but when I try to print it, it prints nothing. Here's how I print it.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in loadedData)
        {
            print("Key = {0}, Value = {1}");
            print(kvp.Key);
            print(kvp.Value);
        }
```

I've also tried

```
string loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<string>(@"{""uni_number"": ""001"",""level"" : ""3"", ""Hp"": ""15""}");

print (loadedData)
```

and it doesn't print anything, so I think I'm using the JsonUtility function wrong, but I don't know how.

If I can't get it to work I could probably make my own function that turns json files into dictionarys, but it's probably going to be a big pain in the but.

Comment: The JSON you posted is very far from being convertible to a `Dictionary<string, string>`, it's rather `Dictionary<int, object>` but, of course, you should create a class instead of using object

Comment: @MyNameIsntBob I'm not sure I understood your need, but if your keys should be the `"1", "2"` etc. Then you can try do that: `string json = @"{""1"":{""uni_number"": 001,""level"" : 3,""Hp"" : 15},""2"":{""uni_number"": 000,""level"" : 0,""Hp"" : 0}}"; Dictionary<string, object> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Convert.ToString(json));` In order to use this you should use Nuget package of `Newtonsoft.Json`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using Newtonsoft.Json and it works :
(notice that each value is a dictionary  (key,value pairs) aswell)

```
     string json = @"{
                    1:
                    {
                        ""uni_number"": 001,
                        ""level"" : 3,
                        ""Hp"" : 15
                    },
                    2:
                    {
                        ""uni_number"": 000,
                        ""level"" : 0,
                        ""Hp"" : 0
                    }
                    }";

        var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>>(json);
        foreach (var uni in values)
        {
            //you can print values here or add to a list or ...
              string uni_number=  uni.Value["uni_number"];
              string level=  uni.Value["level"];
              string Hp=  uni.Value["Hp"];

        }
```

Comment: so I got Newtonsoft.Json installed, and imported it

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

and now the code isn't giving me errors, however, in unity, it's pointing to that line and saying 

`...error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"`

Comment: glad you could find the answer, if you can save to and retrieve from text file then your solutions is ok. i used PlayerPrefs to save serialized dictionary converted to string and it worked. if you found my answer helpful you can mark it as answer , thanks

Comment: Ok, I got that fixed. turns out unity won't let you use that unless you download one of there assets, Link incases anyone needs it. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347

Comment: Fantastic! Just the touch i was needed.